# Unexpected output when using PDO Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm hoping somebody knows what is going on with this. I've never seen anything like this before. I'm trying to re-key the results from an indexed array to a keyed array using the value of 'code' in the results as it is a unique key. This happens in both PHP 5.4.16 and PHP 7.0.10

The following code produces very strange output:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute( $params );

$key = 'code';

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print "Value of $key is '{$row['code']}'\n";
    $rows[ ($row['code']) ] = $row;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
'alue of code is '1286
] => Array
    (
        [code] => 1286
        [EmployeeID] =>
        [Name] =>
    )
```

Notice how the value of $row['code'] is printed to STDOUT after the single quotes and the V in Value is cut off. This causes my re-keyed array ($rows) to have no key value. I've re-keyed arrays from database results thousands of times before and never had a problem until I started using PDO. Anybody have any ideas?

I simplified the quoting by issuing:

```
print "Value of $key is '"."{$row[$key]}"."'\n";
```

which resulted in:

```
'alue of EmployeeCode is '1286
```

I am mystified why it's cutting off the 'V' in Value.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis from the next line. `$rows[$row['code']] = $row;`. Not sure if it will make a difference, but the syntax is odd.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with and without the parens. Same result. But thanks tho.

Comment: `print "Value of $key is " . "{$row['code']}" . "\n";` - Give that a whirl. The concatenation's off and `\n` inside single quotes is also an issue here. @ToddHammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get similar output without using any database calls this way:

```
$row = [
        'code' => "1286\r",
        'EmployeeID' => '',
        'Name' => ''
    ];

print "Value of $key is '{$row['code']}'\n";
$rows[ ($row['code']) ] = $row;
print_r($rows);
```

Output:

```
'alue of  is '1286
Array
(
] => Array
        (
            [code] => 1286
            [EmployeeID] => 
            [Name] => 
        )

)
```

The `\r` character causes the output cursor to jump to the start of the line, so the `'` that's overwriting your 'V' character is actually the *second* single-quote you're printing.

Likewise, in the strange output of print_r(), the `\r` is jumping the output cursor to the start of the line, so the `] => Array` is overwriting what came before it, which was `[1286\r`.

I suspect the data in your database contains literal `\r` characters.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I am so used to trusting my own databases records it never occurred to me to think there is a newline character after the value stored in the data. You fixed it! Thanks again!